# Creating my own vector Class, a lot of errors

Tags: c++, class, vector

I'm fairly new to C++, and creating classes using it, especially using template classes. I have been getting alot of error messages, and I am not sure how to fix them, was hoping someone here could help, thanks in advance.

The Class:

```
template <class T> class Vector {
    public:
        typedef T* iterator;
        Vector();
        iterator begin();
        iterator end();
        int size();
        iterator insert(iterator position, const T& item);
        void alloc_new();

    private:
        T items;
        int used;      
};

template <class T> Vector::Vector() { 
    items = [1000];
    used = 0;
}

template <class T> iterator Vector::begin() {
   return items; 
}

template <class T> iterator Vector::end(){
    return items + used;
}

template <class T> int Vector::size() {
    return used;
}

template <class T> iterator Vector::insert(iterator position, const T& item){

    if (used+1 > items){
        alloc_new();}  

    items[position] = item;
    used =+ 1;

}

template <class T> void Vector::alloc_new(){
        items = used*2;
        T tmp[] = items;

        for (int i = 0; i < used; i++){
            tmp[i] = items[i];
        } 
        delete items;
        items = tmp;
    }
```

The error messages:

```
main.cpp:67: error: `template class Vector' used without template parameters
main.cpp:67: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of `Vector' with no type
main.cpp:67: error: declaration of template `template int Vector()'
main.cpp:52: error: conflicts with previous declaration `template class Vector'
main.cpp:52: error: previous non-function declaration `template class Vector'
main.cpp:67: error: conflicts with function declaration `template int Vector()'
main.cpp: In function `int Vector()':
main.cpp:68: error: `items' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:68: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)
main.cpp:68: error: expected primary-expression before '[' token
main.cpp:69: error: `used' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp: At global scope:
main.cpp:72: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before "Vector"
main.cpp:72: error: expected `;' before "Vector"
main.cpp:76: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before "Vector"
main.cpp:76: error: expected `;' before "Vector"
main.cpp:80: error: `template class Vector' used without template parameters
main.cpp: In function `int size()':
main.cpp:81: error: `used' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp: At global scope:
main.cpp:84: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before "Vector"
main.cpp:84: error: expected `;' before "Vector"
main.cpp:94: error: `template class Vector' used without template parameters
main.cpp: In function `void alloc_new()':
main.cpp:95: error: `items' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:95: error: `used' undeclared (first use this function)
```

Comment: When creating a template one trick is to create it using a concrete type first, such as int. Then, once that is working, abstract away the int to create the template. This method avoids some of the confusing templates messages that the compiler can generate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the template parameters.  For example:

```
template <class T> Vector<T>::Vector() { 
    items = [1000];  // note, this is also invalid syntax
    used = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `Vector::vector()` needs to be changed to `Vector<T>::vector()`. So are the following member functions.
2. `iterator` need to be preceded by `Vector<T>` as `Vector<T>::iterator` since `iterator` is declared inside class `Vector`

Comment: Is this correct?
 `template <class T> Vector<T>::iterator Vector<T>::end()`

Comment: Yes: template <typename T> Vector<T>::iterator Vector<T>::end() is correct, but, of course, you need to know the size of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

since iterator is a nested type of Vector, change

```
template <class T> iterator Vector::begin() { return items; }
```

to

```
template <typename T> Vector<T>::iterator Vector<T>::begin() { return items; }
```

Do this with all the other methods involving iterator, too.